# Determining button's random topMargin

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to place a button in a random location in a relative layout.

As suggested in similar questions I set the leftMargin and topMargin of the button.

I think the calculation should be:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randBtn);
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

params.leftMargin = 
      new Random().nextInt(metrics.widthPixels - activity_h_margin * 2 - b.getWidth());
params.topMargin = 
      new Random().nextInt(metrics.heightPixels - activity_v_margin * 2 - b.getHeight());

b.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For some reason this code does not work well in the vertical axis - sometimes the button gets cut at the bottom of the screen.

This is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/randBtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"        
        android:text="@string/randBtn_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the padding attributes of the relative layout.

Comment: Can you explain? I substracted activity_v_margin * 2 which was supposed to take the padding under consideration.